# SQL Compact 4 File Mode for Web Applications

Tags: web-applications, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

When using SQL Compact 4 in Web Applications, what is the best file mode? Exclusive or Read Write or Shared Read?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.  If all you need to do is read the database, then shared read would be appropriate.  In you need to write to it as well, use read write.  I would avoid the exclusive mode because you do not know how many worker threads IIS will kick off to service multiple visitors.